# Use another video's ffprobe info to convert another video

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm having two files, one `1.mp4` and the other `2.mp4`. I want to use `1.mp4`'s `ffprobe` to convert `2.mp4` using `ffmpeg` so that they have the same dimension and ...
I could naively copy it's info but that's not nice.

Comment: What do you mean *"that's not efficient"*? How else are you going to change a video's size? What did you try? What's the actual problem? What OS do you use? Thank you.

Comment: I want the `2.mp4`'s audio and video codec and dimension and bitrate and ... to be the same as `1.mp4`.
I edited and changed"efficent" to "nice".
I'm on OSX.

Comment: What is the reason that `2.mp4` has to be like `1.mp4`? Copy and paste the complete output of `ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4`. It will output important info required to answer the question.